# Cloudwatch datasource not working after grafana upgrade

Tags: elasticsearch, datasource, upgrade, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

I was working with Grafana 5.x version and elasticsearch 6.4 version. Due to some requirements we need to upgrade Elasticsearch to its 7.0+ version so we did that but the Grafana was still using 5.x version of Elasticsearch Datasource. At Grafana Latest version was not available so we also upgraded Grafana too which cause other datasources like the cloudwatch datasource failed to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

(Taken from question to move to answer, question pending edit approval)
Changed the AWS arn to access key pair in datasource settings and that worked!!